# Symfony 2 / PHP compare the difference of objects in arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I am using Symfony 2.7 I have built a form with an entity, which when submitted returns an array of objects. I need to be able to compare this array of objects with what I have in the that table?

So this is how I have the form setup

```
$builder
   .......
       ->add('my_options',   'entity',  [
                    'label'         => 'Options:',
                    'class'         => 'xxxxBundle:Details',
                    'choice_label'  => 'Title',
                    'multiple'      => true,
                    'expanded'      => true,
                    'required'      => false,
                    'mapped'        => false,
                    'data'          => $data,
                    'attr'          => ['class' => 'AdminList'],
                    'query_builder' =>  function(EntityRepository $er) {
                             return $er->createQueryBuilder('de')
                                        ->where('de.active = ?1')
                                        ->setParameter(1, 1);                                                                             }
       ]);
```

I then do a basic lookup of what my options table has already got,

```
$EditPanels = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getRepository('xxxBundle:Options')
               ->findBy(['AccountID' => $AcID]);
```

This gives me two arrays, one of which the user has just selected (the options they now need on this account) and one with what is already in the database table.

How do I compare these tables to update the rows with the new options, by removing whats not needed and adding in the new options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not even query for existing records. Instead you can:

Persist all new records and update existing:

```
foreach ($new as $object) {
    if ($object->getId() === null) {
        $em->persist($object);
    }
}
$em->flush();
```

Delete all other records from database:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('xxxxBundle:Details')->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->delete()->where($qb->expr()->notIn('id', array_column('id', $new)));
```

P.S. Not sure regarding the syntax, but you got the idea.

Comment: Hi, not sure how this will work, I like the idea but the $object still needs to be bind to an entity? Has this comes form another forms entity? I am sure this is a better method but cant see how to run with it.

Comment: Oh sorry now I see there are two different entities of Options and Details :) What about simply clearing the table and inserting all new data as new records? It should not have a great impact on performance but simplify the logic of the application.

Comment: now thats an idea... I was focused on updating the table. But remove all where X = X and then just add new. I give that a go. I will just had that I do that a working solution (something I will not post) has it is very bad :(

Comment: That works, not the best solution in terms of performance but its only admins that will need to change these options and its unlikely that they will change very offered (if at all). Many thanks. - If you post that as an answer I mark it as true! - Many Thanks Mate!

Comment: Thank you for accepting current answer, I was too lazy to modify it :)

Comment: Thats cool, anyone reading the question should also read the comments :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    $newIds = array_map($formData, function (Details $d) {
        return $d->id;
    });

    $oldIds = array_map($EditPanels, function (Details $d) {
        return $d->id;
    });

    $shouldBeRemoved = array_diff($oldIds, $newIds);
    $shouldBeAdded   = array_diff($newIds, $oldIds);
```

Now you have all the IDs for the Options that need to change. Hope this helps.

Comment: You want to use `array_map` instead of `array_reduce`.

Comment: @moonwave99: You are right, thanks. I've changed the answer.